# Is salesforce REST API support disabled in Enterprise Edition

Tags: rest-api, api

i understand that API support is specially activated for Partner DE applications, so as to also include PE. Even the Salesforce trial EE account, the API call returns a-

```
Error: call to URL https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/ failed with status 403, response [{"message":"The REST API is not enabled for this Organization.","errorCode":"API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG"}], curl_error , curl_errno 0
```

Any work-arounds? i am trying to test the API calls to PE editions from my Parner DE.

Comment: Is your user has API enabled box ticked ?

Comment: Where is that box?

Comment: Its on User profile basically.Check for your sfdc admin profile.Administrative Permissions sections on profile ahould get you the checkbox

Comment: Was your trial EE org upgraded from PE? At any rate, log a "feature enable" support case with Salesforce form your trial EE org and they should enable it for you.